# Adding Constraint to a ScrollView

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, constraints

I have a scrollView that I have stretched the full width of the iOS application in Xcode. I'm using Xcode 6 and size classes so the width is set to 600X600 in the view panel. when I go to add a the constraints in IB, it shows 0 for the top, -16 for the left and right and 0 for the bottom. My question is why does it show -16? It appears as though all sides should display 0. I'm just trying to get a better understanding on how constraints work when using the new size classes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you note the "Constraint to margins" checkbox? Thats what playing tricks with you I think.